# How to test database Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I create `$fake` which have fake data to update.My problem is that `assertDatabaseHas()` return false because generate another fake data. How can I do, that fake data be the same in update form and database ?

```
  public function test_user_update()
    {
        $admin= $this->user->attachRole('admin');

     $fake = [
         'name'        => fake()->name,
         'city'        => fake()->city,
         'date'        => fake()->date
        ];


        $response = $this->actingAs($admin)->putJson(route('user.update', ['update' => $this->user->id]), $fake);
  
        $this->assertDatabaseHas(User::class, $fake);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I perform my release tests with information in the database like this:

```
public function test_country_update_api_json(): void
{
    /** @var Country $country */
    $country = Country::factory()->create();
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $response = $this
        ->actingAs($user)
        ->patchJson(route('country.update', $country->id), [
            "name" => "test",
        ]);

    $response->assertOk();

    $this->assertTrue(collect($response->decodeResponseJson())
        ->pluck('response.name')->contains('test'));
}
```